# read/write to a resource in .net

Tags: c#, .net, resources

In my c# program I need to read 1 string (the string is a file path).  Occasionally I need to write over this file path with a different one.  Creating a .txt file as a resource seemed like a good idea but as I found out it is not a good way to write something to.  My only other thought is to get a database involved but that seems like overkill for just 1 string.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why is writing to a text file not a good way?

Comment: Could you please explain in a bit more depth what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 1) A configuration file. 2) An .INI file. 3) A registry entry. 4) A text file on disk. Search here for `[c#] store config info` - this question has been asked many times before. Here, I [found one for you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16594730/62576).

Comment: Unless the path is sensitive for some reason, consider using app.config or add a "Settings" file to your project. These are both easy to read in code and are standard ways to have configurable settings for your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you're after is a string within the lifetime of the application, using a `static` string in your program would be the best way to go. You'll also want to do this even with the selections below, as reading from an external data storage for *every* operation is inefficient, but often you only read when the program starts up and keep the value in memory after that.

If the string needs to *exceed* the lifetime of your application, which is to say be available and consistent as the program is opened and closed, then you need external data, be it a database, registry entry, or good old config file.

Going the easiest route, a config file should be somewhere your program can always get to it, doesn't move, and most configs lie outside the user's typical areas (don't store it in My Documents). `"%APPDATA%\YourProgramName\Config.xml` is the most obvious location. See [`ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for turning those variables into usable locations.

Comment: The first line of your post makes a *big* assumption.

Comment: Which is why the second paragraph goes into details about what to do *in the other case*

Comment: A settings entry would work much easier than a config file.  Clearly however, OP has no interest in following up with a question that can be answered properly.

Comment: @papgomez I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "settings entry," so *I* would at least welcome another answer in such a direction.

Comment: [Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) and an [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881415/c-sharp-settings-default-save-not-saving) [in such a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application) [direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789252/properties-settings-default-save-where-is-that-file)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to write a string in a text file, write it in xml format or try using `Xmlserializer` to serialize your class.

And if only one string is involved then try using static property and access it with static class for global use in your application